# getStaticPath and the need for filetype in the URL

Tags: next.js, getstaticprops, getstaticpaths

In `/pages` I have `[page].js` and `index.js`.

`[page].js` generate needed Pages by the Value of "CustomPage". It's content comes from an Data-JSON-File.

It work like expected, as long as I start on the Homepage and use links inside of my Webpage.
For example I have 2 Pages for now: /impressum and /datenschutz.

So clicking the link "Impressum" open `myDomain.com/impressum` (and it work, BUT notice, there is no .html at the end).
**BUT**, if I refresh the page, or type `myDomain.com/impressum` directly in the addressbar of the browser, I got an not found error (from nginx-server, not from next!).

## Second try

As I need a fully static page and I've added `getStaticPath` and `getStaticProps` in the file for testing purposes, so that "real" html-files will be created:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

import Index from './index';
import config from '../content/config.yml';
import CustomPage from '../src/components/CustomPage';

const RoutingPage = () => {
  const { customPages } = config;
  const router = useRouter();
  const { page } = router.query;

  const findMatches = (requestedPage) =>
    customPages.find((customPage) => customPage.name === requestedPage) ||
    false;

  const customPageData = findMatches(page);
  if (customPageData !== false) {
    return <CustomPage pageContext={customPageData} />;
  }

  return page === 'index' ? (
    <Index page={page} />
  ) : (
    <p style={{ marginTop: '250px' }}>whats up {page}</p>
  );
};

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { page: 'impressum' } },
      { params: { page: 'datenschutz' } },
    ],
    fallback: false, // See the "fallback" section below
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  return { props: { page: params.page } };
}

export default RoutingPage;
```

This generates the single pages as real html-files:
[image]

But this lead me to the next issue:
I've implemented internal Links in the Webpage like this:
[image]

which still lead a user to `myDomain.com/impressum`, now additionally there is `myDomain.com/impressum.html` available. From SEO perspective, this are two different paths.

How do I get them unified, so that I have only one path - regardles of whether if I open it from within my Webpage, or enter it directly.

### Workaround Idea (??)

Sure, I could everywhere use something like:

```
<Link href={`/${item.page}.html`}>
```

But this only work if the Page is exported and copied to the Server. For `next dev` and `next start` this won't work, because the .html-File don't exist.... and so I'll lost the "page preview" while working at the page.

So only Idea I have is to set an ENV-Variable for `.env.development` & `.env.production` and encapsulate the -Component from NEXT in a HOC.
In that HOC I could check if I'm currently in dev or prod and don't use .html for those links... otherwise add the .html to the link.

What **YOU** say about this. Do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's `state of the art`, but as little workaround I did this:

I place the `next/link`-Component in a HOC and check if it's run on development or production (process.env.NODE_ENV):

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';

const LinkHoc = (props) => {
  const { as, href, children } = props;
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    return (
      <Link
        {...props}
        as={as ? `${as}.html` : ''}
        href={href ? `${href}.html` : ''}
      />
    );
  }
  return <Link {...props}>{children}</Link>;
};
export default LinkHoc;
```

With this workaround you get `mydomain.com/impressum` links in DEV and `mydomain.com/impressum.html` in production.

Only thing what to do at least is to rename the JSON-Files for the generated pages.
They are in `/out/_next/data/XYZranadomString/`.
They are named like `impressum.json` and you need to rename it to `impressum.html.json` to  fix the 404 error on clientside for this files.

### Would love to see a better Solution, so if you have any suggestions, please let me know!